# Problem with Android Studio emulator, keep missing (maybe crashing)

Tags: android-studio

I tried to find some solution on Stack Overflow, but it seems like there isn't any similar problem.

I am new to Android Studio development. The emulator keeps missing after running for a while or I click a few things on the emulator or in my own built application. It is like a crash, but does not show any crash messages; the emulator will directly go missing and show this picture below. What's the problem?

I tried the solution of wiping all the data on the virtual device, still had the problem

[image: Problem with the emulator]

Comment: Did you generate a Virtual Device in Virtual Device Managment?

Comment: I generated a Virtual Device using Virtual Device Configuration

Comment: And chose a device when you run the application?

Comment: Please refer to the video link, it will crash like this: https://youtu.be/8cJU46GI-P4. I have no idea it is crashing or not

Comment: Even though I am not running any application sometimes, by just running the emulator, it will be gone suddenly like in the video sometime. I don't know what causing this issue, tried to re-create a virtual device, still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The issue is still not solved yet, but I decided to use [React Native](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)#React_Native) with the Android Studio emulator. It works without crashing.